# Which is the default java version that is used with selenium + protractor

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

Because of different platforms, and different java versions, some tests fail on mac platform that pass on windows platform and vice versa.

Additional: 
Tested the same tests with Java 6 and Java 8, and the same thing is happening. Some test fail|pass with Java 6, that pass|fail with Java 8, so it is not problem in different browsers.

Comment: What do you mean by "default java version"? Do you mean what versions are compatible?

Comment: I would like to know, which is the best version of java with selenium + protractor, so we can set the testing env.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that it is related to Java. It is probably because of different browsers, Selenium compatibility issues.

Anyway, you can set up the same version of Java (use the latest) and check. Selenium prints the used version of Java when it starts.

Answer (score 0):

- Selenium webdriver is compatible till Java 1.7
- Selenium geckodriver need Java 1.8 at least

However **Protractor** works with **geckodriver** hence it needs [Java 1.8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html) by default.

[Protractor with Java 1.8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyzdt.png)